# FUSE ESB - CXF Webservice Fault

Tags: web-services, cxf, apache-camel, fuseesb

I have a CXF webservice exposed in FUSE ESB.  In case of an exception a SOAP Fault is thrown from the application and the response is coming as below in SOAP UI.  What should I do to avoid/remove the classContext tags in the response.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
     <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
     <faultstring>8001 - The request context failed authentication policy!</faultstring>
     <detail>
        <PolicyException xmlns="http://www.example.com/com/xyz/sdp/api/ws"/>
        <ns1:PolicyException xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/com/xyz/sdp/api/ws">
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">com.xyz.sdp.api.processors.request.AuthenticationProcessor</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorEndpoint</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorEndpoint$1</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.camel.processor.TryProcessor</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.camel.processor.TryProcessor</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfConsumer$1</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfConsumer$1</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">java.util.concurrent.FutureTask</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceServletHandler</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerHandlerCollection</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3</classContext>
           <classContext xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">java.lang.Thread</classContext>
           <faultInfo xsi:type="ns2:PFaultInfo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns6="http://ws.hij.com/mno/mci" xmlns:ns5="http://www.hij.com/mno/service/management-v8" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.hij.com/mno/userprofile-v2" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.hij.com/mno/commerce/v6" xmlns:ns2="http://ca.abc.sdp.xyz.com/">
              <code>8001</code>
              <message>The request context failed authentication policy!</message>
           </faultInfo>
        </ns1:PolicyException>
     </detail>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: I think there is some option your can turn off on CXF to not include stacktrace in SOAP faults.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug due to Karaf, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KARAF-4429,
which uses an endorsed java.lang.Exception that is replacing the JDK one to provide enhanced logging capability.

Thanks to this feature, you are able to get full OSGi info on the StackTrace entry in the logs (have you seen the square brackets with the [bundleId:bundleSymbolicName:bundleVersion] when you send the log:display command?) but it introduces a bug that prevents SOAP Fault to be marshalled properly by JaxB.

Until the Karaf Issue is solved, you could workaround the problem in your Fuse ESB instance by deleting the the file:

```
{FUSE_ESB_HOME}/lib/endorsed/org.apache.karaf.exception-x.x.x.jar
```

you'll loose OSGi info on some elements of the StackTrace in the logs but everything else should work right.

Answer (score 0):

See this page, at the section *SOAP Fault for debugging*

- http://cxf.apache.org/docs/debugging-and-logging.html

About the options to turn on|off stacktraces and whatnot.